# Is the correct way to adjust for covariates in a linear model comparing two models or just one?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

Whenever I run a multiple linear regression adjusted for covariates, I first run a linear model of the outcome against the covariates (Model 1) and then run a linear model of the outcome against the covariates + the exposure of interest (Model 2). Then I run an anova comparing the two models.

To me, this is basically addressing the question "how much does the exposure of interest increase the predictive power of the model above and beyond the covariates alone?", and that is what seems to be most important to me. This is always how I have run multiple linear regression when adjusting for covariates.

However, I was just speaking with a collaborator who simply runs one linear model with the outcome, covariates, and exposure of interest (Model 2), and takes the coefficients and p-values from that. To me, that is not the same as "adjusting" for covariates.

I'm wondering which is correct when performing multiple linear regression adjusted for covariates? Compare two models (Model 1 = covariates only; Model 2 = covariates + exposure of interest), or just take the coefficients and p-values from Model 2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard multiple linear regression, your two procedures are equivalent: the p-value from an ANOVA comparing two models that only differ by one term (in this case, your exposure of interest), and the p-value for the coefficient of that term in the full model should yield the same result. So, both of you are correct!

In the full model, the coefficient of each term is estimating the effect conditional on the other covariates in the model. The p-value is the result of testing the hypothesis that the exposure term has no association, holding the other covariates fixed, versus the alternative that the exposure term does have an association, holding the other covariates fixed. That's why this approach is still adjusting for the other covariates.

Comment: Wow, interesting, I never realized this! Thanks so much.